# $(...).counterUp is not a function WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-waypoints

Unsure why `$(...).counterUp is not a function`.

- `Waypoints` is enqueued after `Counter-up`.
- WP core JQuery is loaded before both of them.

**View source ordering:**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://testsite.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Counter-Up/1.0.0/jquery.counterup.min.js?ver=5.2.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.js?ver=5.2.3'></script>
```

How I'm enqueuing `Waypoints` and `CounterUp`:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'counterup', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Counter-Up/1.0.0/jquery.counterup.min.js', array(), false, false);
wp_enqueue_script( 'waypoints', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.js', array(), false, false);
```

**JS being used:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.counter').counterUp({
        delay: 10,
        time: 1000
    });
});
```

What am I missing here?

**Edit:**

Screenshots of where files are loaded:

[image]
[image]

Have also tried pulling `counterup` via `node_modules`:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'counterup', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'node_modules/counterup/jquery.counterup.min.js' );
```

... Still get the same error message.

Comment: Check for any other inclusions of jQuery. Eg, you may have another `<script src="...jquery.js">` somewhere further down the document

Comment: Hi @Phil - The WordPress core JQuery is the only inclusion of JQuery that is on the page (and site)

Comment: when you initialize the Counter code before loading jquery.counterup.min.js?

Comment: @Vel - The counter code compiles into `theme.min.js` and `theme.min.js` is loaded right before the closing `body` tag. So yes, JQuery is loaded before `counterUp` is called.

Comment: can you share the screenshot?

Comment: @Vel - Sure, you want a screenshot of where the files are loaded in from view source?

Comment: Yes. that screenshot.

Comment: @Vel - Updated question with screenshot :)

Comment: Please download and use counterup.js from your local server

Comment: @Vel - As in via `node_modules`? Because I have tried that way too, see updated question

Comment: Why you are using node module?. node module not require. simple download and include the your theme folder.

Comment: Make sure you do an exhaustive search for any other jQuery inclusions. Check every `<script>` in _view source_ tag and also use your browser's _Sources_ developer console tab.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this with the information given ~ https://jsfiddle.net/06akedqs/. I definitely think this is a duplicate jQuery problem as demonstrated here ~ https://jsfiddle.net/06akedqs/1/

Answer (score 1):

1. Download `jquery.counterup.min.js` and include in your active theme folder/js.
2. Add below the script in functions.php file.

   ```
   function counterup_scripts() 
   {
        wp_enqueue_script('counterup', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.counterup.min.js', array(), false, false);

   }
   add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'counterup_scripts');
   ```

Comment: I have just tried that (and also deregisted WordPress core JQuery and registered the JQuery 3.4.1) but still getting the `counterUp is not a function` error?

Comment: Did you download the counterup.js to local server?